# Is there any way to get list of all attachments of Trello board? (via API)

Tags: trello

I am looking for a way to list all attachments related to a Trello board, but all I found is getting a list of attachments related to a **card**. Is there any way to get list of all board attachments without enumerating over every single card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GET /1/board/[board_id]/cards](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-cards) with `attachments=true` to get all of the attachments at once.  You'll still have to iterate over the cards, but it only requires one request, rather than one per card.

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter by "has:attachments"

Answer (score 0):

A heavily requested feature for Trello users of Bridge24, we are excited to provide access to the File Download Manager. This allows the punctual or bulk download for files (attachments) associated with cards (documents, images, other) within a card, a search set of cards, a board, or across multiple boards. It has been optimized to track the transfer status and provides an index and log, in structured zip files. Whether just with a few attachments or a full backup of 10s of GBs of files, this feature is robust and gets the job done!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuNlH.png)